# EntityFramework and Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two object Classes

```
 class Person
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set;}
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsMale { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual  PersonInfo PersonInfo { get; set; }

}
```

and :

```
class PhoneNumber
{

    public enum PhoneType
    { Work, Mobile, Home };

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public PhoneType phoneType { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

I added "virtual" keyword to my navigation properties to enable LazyLoading, then i added some codes for getting list of persons:

```
using (var newContext = new MyDbContext())

    {
        var selectedPerson = newContext.Persons.ToList();  
    }
```

But, when i run my project, i get the PhoneNumber being null!
I thought if i add "virtual" keyword to my navigation properties then i get the PhoneNumber as well..
I got it all wrong?

Comment: have you turned lazy loading on?

Comment: I think it is enough if i add "virtual" keyword to my navigation keywords like: person and phone number !!!

Comment: Yes, you think so but it's not.

Comment: Make sure you have `newContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` equal to `true`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, i did it, but its not work!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, i should added public modifier to my object classes so :

```
 Public class Person
  {

     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set;}
     public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
     public bool IsMale { get; set; }
     public byte[] Image { get; set; }
     public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
     public virtual Person Parent { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumber { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
     public virtual  PersonInfo PersonInfo { get; set; }

  }
```

and :

```
 Public class PhoneNumber
  {

    public enum PhoneType
    { Work, Mobile, Home };

     public int id { get; set; }
     public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
     public PhoneType phoneType { get; set; }
     public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First: I don't know if that makes any difference but I have configured my navigation properties as `List<T>` and lazy loading works.

Maybe with `ICollection<T>` EF does not initialize these collections because it does not know which concrete list type to use (just a guess)

```
 public virtual List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
```

Second: By default you don't have to explicitly configure something, it should work out of the box. Anyway, make sure you don't disable `LazyLoadingEnabled` and `ProxyCreationEnabled`

Third: Enum Data types are supported since EF5 with Framework 4.5 (if you still run Framework 4.0 you should set it `phoneType` to int

Comment: Thanks.. are Lazy Loading and Proxy  enabled by default in EntityFramework5?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I never explicitly set those values in my config and it works. You can check that with `var person = context.Persons.Find(1);` Now check person.GetType().Name - it should be something like `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Person_ABCBE0D1022D01EB84B81873D49DEECC60879FC4152BB115215C3EC16FB8003A` and person.PhoneNumbers should be an empty list even if no related records are available.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
using (var newContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var selectedPerson = newContext.Persons.ToList();  
}
```

will never load `PhoneNumbers` (or any navigation property) because you don't `Include` them. And after the statement has run the context is disposed, so any lazy loading attempt will throw an exception.

So (assuming that you didn't disable lazy loading in the context by setting either `LazyLoadingEnabled` or `ProxyCreationEnabled` = false.) you should either include the `PhoneNumbers`

```
var selectedPerson = newContext.Persons.Include(p => p.PhoneNumbers).ToList();
```

or address a person's `PhoneNumbers` collection within the lifespan of the context. (Which will execute additional SQL queries).

Comment: I think it is enough if i add "virtual" to my navigation property, in your code, you demand something like this : Person Join with Phone, so you explicitly do the loading and it is not Lazy loading.

Comment: No, that's not lazy, but I also indicated the conditions for lazy loading to succeed.